# How can I add equal spacing between two equal sized columns without reducing the number of columns in bootstrap 4?

Tags: bootstrap-4

```
<div class="row mx-auto green-row-sub-row  d-flex justify-content-center">
     `<div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 ml-sm-0 my-md-1 borders green-row-sub-columns ">
       </div>`

     `<div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6  my-md-1 ml-sm-0 borders green-row-sub-columns">
      </div>`
</div>
```

here is the **style.css**

```
.green-row-sub-row
{
    width: 100%;
    height: 94%;
}

.green-row-sub-columns
{
    background-color: rgb(125, 141, 186);
}
```

I wanna add in-between spacing between the columns without reducing the number of
columns

Answer (score 0):

Use padding or margins to add spacing between.

Bootstrap includes a wide range of shorthand responsive margin and padding utility classes to modify an element’s appearance.

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/spacing/

Comment: yes but when I apply padding and margins the whole column goes to the new line as I both of the columns are six in size => Total =12

Comment: You need to wrap them in a new div, see my JSFiddle https://jsfiddle.net/7ua61ghc/27/